# WordPress website hook error

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have a problem with my site. I migrate the website to another hosting provider and website not working now. I dont know why. I tried reinstalling the files, WordPress version, turn off the plugins and nothing happend.

Is there anybody with experience in this error?

> Fatal error: Class 'Requests_Hooks' not found in
>   /data/www/22560/nejrychlejsiauta_cz/www/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php
>   on line 17

Comment: Try re-loading wordpress from a clean source - sounds like it is missing some files or not upgraded some files.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the folder "Requests" does not exist, try to get it from another WordPress installation of the same version, compress it and upload it to the site where the error is, then unzip it and it will work.

Regards..

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me with this same exact error. I had the file Hooks.php that went missing. It is located here: wp-includes/Request/   With my install theres a file named Hooker.php and Hooks.php in that same directory.  I had an identical install in another directory for a diff site and after cross checking the files, Hooks.php was missing on the broken website. After I installed it back on the site, the site works fine.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This happens in a case when you copy, e.g. in Total Commander, and have left the field "**convert file names to lowercase**" checked. As the path to the class file is not `wp-includes/requests/hooks.php` but `wp-includes/Requests/Hooks.php`
So **uncheck** this option.